# Java no longer found by my games or in command line after updating steam deck

Tags: java, linux, minecraft, steam, arch-linux

When I updated my steam deck Prism Minecraft launcher no longer found a java install.

I used the command `java --version` and got back `bash: java: command not found`

Seeing that java must have been unintalled somehow with the update I decided to reinstall java using `sudo pacman -S jre17-openjdk jre8-openjdk` and got back

```
warning: jre17-openjdk-17.0.5.u1-1 is up to date -- reinstalling
warning: jre8-openjdk-8.345.u01-1 is up to date -- reinstalling
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (2) jre17-openjdk-17.0.5.u1-1  jre8-openjdk-8.345.u01-1

Total Installed Size:  0.90 MiB
Net Upgrade Size:      0.00 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] y
(2/2) checking keys in keyring                                                                [#######################################################] 100%
(2/2) checking package integrity                                                              [#######################################################] 100%
(2/2) loading package files                                                                   [#######################################################] 100%
(2/2) checking for file conflicts                                                             [#######################################################] 100%
(2/2) checking available disk space                                                           [#######################################################] 100%
warning: could not get file information for usr/lib/jvm/
warning: could not get file information for usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk/
warning: could not get file information for usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk/lib/
warning: could not get file information for usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk/lib/libawt_xawt.debuginfo
warning: could not get file information for usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk/lib/libawt_xawt.so
warning: could not get file information for usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk/lib/libjawt.debuginfo
warning: could not get file information for usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk/lib/libjawt.so
warning: could not get file information for usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk/lib/libjsound.debuginfo
warning: could not get file information for usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk/lib/libjsound.so
warning: could not get file information for usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk/lib/libsplashscreen.debuginfo
warning: could not get file information for usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk/lib/libsplashscreen.so
warning: could not get file information for usr/share/licenses/jre17-openjdk
warning: could not get file information for usr/lib/jvm/
warning: could not get file information for usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/
warning: could not get file information for usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/
warning: could not get file information for usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/bin/
warning: could not get file information for usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/bin/policytool
warning: could not get file information for usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/lib/
warning: could not get file information for usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64/
warning: could not get file information for usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64/libjsound.so
warning: could not get file information for usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64/libjsoundalsa.so
warning: could not get file information for usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64/libsplashscreen.so
warning: could not get file information for usr/share/licenses/java8-openjdk/
warning: could not get file information for usr/share/licenses/jre8-openjdk
warning: could not get file information for usr/share/man/
warning: could not get file information for usr/share/man/ja/
warning: could not get file information for usr/share/man/ja/man1/
warning: could not get file information for usr/share/man/ja/man1/policytool-openjdk8.1.gz
warning: could not get file information for usr/share/man/man1/
warning: could not get file information for usr/share/man/man1/policytool-openjdk8.1.gz
:: Processing package changes...
error: cannot remove file '/usr/': Read-only file system
(1/2) reinstalling jre17-openjdk                                                              [#######################################################] 100%
warning: warning given when extracting /usr/lib/jvm/ (Can't create '/usr/lib/jvm')
warning: warning given when extracting /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk/ (Failed to create dir '/usr/lib/jvm')
warning: warning given when extracting /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk/lib/ (Failed to create dir '/usr/lib/jvm')
warning: warning given when extracting /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk/lib/libawt_xawt.debuginfo (Failed to create dir '/usr/lib/jvm')
warning: warning given when extracting /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk/lib/libawt_xawt.so (Failed to create dir '/usr/lib/jvm')
warning: warning given when extracting /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk/lib/libjawt.debuginfo (Failed to create dir '/usr/lib/jvm')
warning: warning given when extracting /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk/lib/libjawt.so (Failed to create dir '/usr/lib/jvm')
warning: warning given when extracting /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk/lib/libjsound.debuginfo (Failed to create dir '/usr/lib/jvm')
warning: warning given when extracting /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk/lib/libjsound.so (Failed to create dir '/usr/lib/jvm')
warning: warning given when extracting /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk/lib/libsplashscreen.debuginfo (Failed to create dir '/usr/lib/jvm')
warning: warning given when extracting /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk/lib/libsplashscreen.so (Failed to create dir '/usr/lib/jvm')
warning: warning given when extracting /usr/share/licenses/jre17-openjdk (Can't create '/usr/share/licenses/jre17-openjdk')
/tmp/alpm_JkUPEu/.INSTALL: line 5: /usr/bin/archlinux-java: No such file or directory
/tmp/alpm_JkUPEu/.INSTALL: line 33: /usr/bin/archlinux-java: No such file or directory
error: command failed to execute correctly
error: cannot remove file '/usr/': Read-only file system
(2/2) reinstalling jre8-openjdk                                                               [#######################################################] 100%
warning: warning given when extracting /usr/lib/jvm/ (Can't create '/usr/lib/jvm')
warning: warning given when extracting /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/ (Failed to create dir '/usr/lib/jvm')
warning: warning given when extracting /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/ (Failed to create dir '/usr/lib/jvm')
warning: warning given when extracting /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/bin/ (Failed to create dir '/usr/lib/jvm')
warning: warning given when extracting /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/bin/policytool (Failed to create dir '/usr/lib/jvm')
warning: warning given when extracting /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/lib/ (Failed to create dir '/usr/lib/jvm')
warning: warning given when extracting /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64/ (Failed to create dir '/usr/lib/jvm')
warning: warning given when extracting /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64/libjsound.so (Failed to create dir '/usr/lib/jvm')
warning: warning given when extracting /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64/libjsoundalsa.so (Failed to create dir '/usr/lib/jvm')
warning: warning given when extracting /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64/libsplashscreen.so (Failed to create dir '/usr/lib/jvm')
warning: warning given when extracting /usr/share/licenses/java8-openjdk/ (Can't create '/usr/share/licenses/java8-openjdk')
warning: warning given when extracting /usr/share/licenses/jre8-openjdk (Can't create '/usr/share/licenses/jre8-openjdk')
warning: warning given when extracting /usr/share/man/ (Can't create '/usr/share/man')
warning: warning given when extracting /usr/share/man/ja/ (Failed to create dir '/usr/share/man')
warning: warning given when extracting /usr/share/man/ja/man1/ (Failed to create dir '/usr/share/man')
warning: warning given when extracting /usr/share/man/ja/man1/policytool-openjdk8.1.gz (Failed to create dir '/usr/share/man')
warning: warning given when extracting /usr/share/man/man1/ (Failed to create dir '/usr/share/man')
warning: warning given when extracting /usr/share/man/man1/policytool-openjdk8.1.gz (Failed to create dir '/usr/share/man')
/tmp/alpm_PZmAp8/.INSTALL: line 5: /usr/bin/archlinux-java: No such file or directory
/tmp/alpm_PZmAp8/.INSTALL: line 33: /usr/bin/archlinux-java: No such file or directory
error: command failed to execute correctly
:: Running post-transaction hooks...
(1/1) Arming ConditionNeedsUpdate...
touch: setting times of '/usr': Read-only file system
error: command failed to execute correctly
```

"warning: jre17-openjdk-17.0.5.u1-1 is up to date -- reinstalling" seems to indicate that java is still installed but nothing I have tried can find it. I need to find it so I can put a path to it in the prism launcher.
Theres a lot going on here. Any help would be appricated for the Linux noob.

Comment: This is a programming site, but somehow, I don't think you're trying to program anything. You might have gotten lost on the way to Steam support. Log into Steam. Find the tech support link. Contact them.

Comment: Steam OS uses an immutable root partition. You should keep it that way. Manually installing to your home folder could be a solution.